# "Call to undefined method Calendar\Library\Carbon::setWeekStartsAt()" Solspace Calendar

Tags: plugin-solspacecalendar

I've got Solspace Calendar installed to the best of my knowledge. I have repurposed the 'calendar_demo' files to 'calendar'. Both /calendar and /calendar_demo just show:

> "Call to undefined method Calendar\Library\Carbon::setWeekStartsAt()" in DateHelper.php.

/calendar/week does the same. A path like calendar/2016/11 just give a Twig error.

I can't understand why this is happening. I'll give more details if you ask me, I don't know what else to give.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Solspace on the chance it's a bug?

Comment: Just to clarify, does this error happen when you use the demo templates (without modifying templates, paths, etc)?

Comment: @solspace. Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I happens on my local and dev environments.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with another third party plugin ([Postmaster](https://github.com/objectivehtml/Postmaster-for-Craft-CMS)) installed and also using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com). The Postmaster plugin appears to be using an older copy of Carbon and Calendar is loading Postmaster's Carbon library, causing issues.

Manually updating the **vendors** directory to use latest versions may resolve this issue. We will try to reach out to the developer of Postmaster and see if they can resolve this on their end. :)

Customers effected with this issue can contact [Solspace support](https://solspace.com/craft/create-ticket/calendar) for an updated **vendors** folder for Postmaster that may resolve the issue.